# AmCharts - show tooltip for all categories in stacked bar chart

Tags: tooltip, amcharts, amcharts4, stacked-chart

I'm working on a stacked bar chart and want to display the tooltip for all categories at the same time when hovering one of them.

For instance, in this amCharts demo code I want to show the tooltip for marketing (purple) for all countries when hovering one country.

```
// Apply chart themes
am4core.useTheme(am4themes_animated);
am4core.useTheme(am4themes_kelly);

// Create chart instance
var chart = am4core.create("chartdiv", am4charts.XYChart);

chart.marginRight = 400;

// Add data
chart.data = [{
  "country": "Lithuania",
  "research": 501.9,
  "marketing": 250,
  "sales": 199
}, {
  "country": "Czech Republic",
  "research": 301.9,
  "marketing": 222,
  "sales": 251
}, {
  "country": "Ireland",
  "research": 201.1,
  "marketing": 170,
  "sales": 199
}, {
  "country": "Germany",
  "research": 165.8,
  "marketing": 122,
  "sales": 90
}, {
  "country": "Australia",
  "research": 139.9,
  "marketing": 99,
  "sales": 252
}, {
  "country": "Austria",
  "research": 128.3,
  "marketing": 85,
  "sales": 84
}, {
  "country": "UK",
  "research": 99,
  "marketing": 93,
  "sales": 142
}, {
  "country": "Belgium",
  "research": 60,
  "marketing": 50,
  "sales": 55
}, {
  "country": "The Netherlands",
  "research": 50,
  "marketing": 42,
  "sales": 25
}];

//console.log('chart', chart);

// Create axes
var categoryAxis = chart.xAxes.push(new am4charts.CategoryAxis());
categoryAxis.dataFields.category = "country";
categoryAxis.title.text = "Local country offices";
categoryAxis.renderer.grid.template.location = 0;
categoryAxis.renderer.minGridDistance = 20;


var  valueAxis = chart.yAxes.push(new am4charts.ValueAxis());
valueAxis.title.text = "Expenditure (M)";

// Create series
var series = chart.series.push(new am4charts.ColumnSeries());
series.dataFields.valueY = "research";
series.dataFields.categoryX = "country";
series.name = "Research";
series.tooltipText = "{name}: [bold]{valueY}[/]";
series.stacked = true;

var series2 = chart.series.push(new am4charts.ColumnSeries());
series2.dataFields.valueY = "marketing";
series2.dataFields.categoryX = "country";
series2.name = "Marketing";
series2.tooltipText = "{name}: [bold]{valueY}[/]";
series2.stacked = true;

var series3 = chart.series.push(new am4charts.ColumnSeries());
series3.dataFields.valueY = "sales";
series3.dataFields.categoryX = "country";
series3.name = "Sales";
series3.tooltipText = "{name}: [bold]{valueY}[/]";
series3.stacked = true;

// Add cursor
chart.cursor = new am4charts.XYCursor();

https://codepen.io/team/amcharts/pen/GdQWxz
```

I tried using a cursor but that only shows all tooltips for the specific category. I tried to add an event handler without any luck.

Anyone have a suggestion if it's do-able.

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: Unfortunately not

Comment: I found it, check this https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-v6rynn?file=src%2Fapp%2Fbar-graph%2Fbar-graph.component.ts